# Does anyone knows if python can use the message group in activemq

Tags: python, django, activemq-classic

Our project use Django and my leader want me to use the message group in activemq, but I did't find how to use it with python, I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python package [stomp](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py). See usage for examples.

Comment: I use it to connect the activemq, I can do some simple things, like connect, send, are you sure it this module can use the message group